# Excel not showing a row but python displaying it

Tags: python, excel, xlrd

I'm trying to read from an excel sheet in python:

```
>>> import xlrd
>>> book = xlrd.open_workbook("file.xlsx")
>>> sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0
... )
>>> value = worksheet.cell(1,1)
>>> print(value)
text:u'awx aaw('
```

But when I do the same for row 195, I get `error:29`:

```
>>> value = sheet.cell(195,1)
>>> print(value)
error:29
```

What does this mean? I can't even see anything "29" in the excel sheet. Row 195 is something else there. I even tried to unhide rows, but nothing happened. Please help, this is creating problems for the rest of program as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That value indicates that the cell value is the error `#NAME?`.
See line 106 in xlrd/biffh.py for details.